# PrimeFaces 8.0 DefaultStreamedContent.builder().stream() asks for SerializableSupplier<InputStream>

Tags: java, inputstream, primefaces-8.0

In PrimeFaces 8.0 the `DefaultStreamedContent` cannot be initialized like `new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream, contentType, name)` because it has been deprecated, instead you shound use `DefaultStreamedContent.builder()`.

Although while doing `.stream()` it asks for a `SerializableSupplier<InputStream>` instead of an `InputStream` like in the version before 8.0.

```
DefaultStreamedContent.builder().contentType(contentType).name(name).stream(is).build();
                                                                            ^^
```

How can I convert a `InputStream` to a `SerializableSupplier`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Everthing is in the migration guide here: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide.

in general the following will work:

```
DefaultStreamedContent.builder().contentType(contentType).name(name).stream(() -> is).build();
```

But the idea behind the change is a different.
If you use a RequestScoped bean to build the StreamedContent, your bean and therefore the StreamedContent will be created twice:

1. when rendering the view
2. when streaming the resource (this is a new browser request!)

In this case, your `is` will probably created 2 times. Most of the times this results in 1 useless IO access or DB call.

To only create the `is` one time, you should lazy initialize it via the supplier lambda:

```
DefaultStreamedContent.builder().contentType(contentType).name(name).stream(() -> new FileInputStream(....)).build();
```

Comment: Is FileInputStream initialized in stream() autoclosable?

Comment: It will be close automatically, yes: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/application/resource/StreamedContentHandler.java#L124

Comment: @tandraschko can you clarify for the latest version (Primefaces 10)? I cannot seem to find the place where the input stream gets closed anymore...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
DataHandler dataHandler = someBean.getFileData();
byte contents[] = IOUtils.toByteArray(dataHandler.getInputStream());
StreamedContent streamedContent = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                    .name(someBean.getFileName())
                    .contentType("application/octet-stream")
                    .stream(() -> new ByteArrayInputStream(contents)).build();
```

Comment: You should also get the dataHandler + init contents[] inside the stream lambda

Answer (score 0):

The lazy initialize answer above by @tandraschko did not work for me in Netbeans using java 8. I had to have the FileInputStream created before injecting it into the builder.

So my code looks like :

```
public StreamedContent getFiledownload() {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("...");
        filedownload = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                .contentType("...")
                .name("...")
                .stream(() -> fis)
                .build();
        return filedownload;
    }
```

Thought I would comment just in case someone else was running into compiling issues.

Answer (score -1):

For MySQL stored image I use this:

```
resultset = statement.executeQuery("call sp_query()");
if(resultset.next()) {

    new DefaultStreamedContent();
    StreamedContent photo = DefaultStreamedContent.builder().contentType("contentType").name("name").stream(() -> resultset.getBinaryStream("picture")).build());
}

// Close the connection
con.close();
```